# Problem with - with_items inside regex_findall

Tags: ansible

I'm new on the forum and I'm really sorry if I will describe something wrongly.

I can't figure out how to use iteam inside regex:

This is an output from variable search_01

```
ok: [sample_host] => {

    "msg": [
        "text 01 \n",
        "text 02 \n",
        "text 03 \n",
        "text 04 \n""
    ]
```

This is an output from variable search_02

```
ok: [sample_host] => {

    "msg": [
        "10"
        "03"
        "08"
    ]
```

This is my code

```
 - name: "Sample"
   set_fact:    
     find_variable: "{{ search_01 | regex_findall(item) }}"
   with_items: "{{ search_02 }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Sample TASK] ****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [sample_host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ search_01 | regex_findall(item) }}): expected string or buffer"}
```

Any idea why it's not working? Or maybe I should use a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found an answer:

```html
  - name: "Sample"
    set_fact:
      find_variable: "{{ search_01 | string | regex_findall(item) }}"
    when: 'item in (search_01 | string)'
    with_items: "{{ search_02 }}"
```